# Axios request after state update in React (to use state value in url)

Tags: reactjs, axios, geolocation

I would like to make an axios request, but I need a state update with gelocation value before.
I tried this :

```
    const Home = () => {

  const [lat, setLat] = useState();
  const [long, setLong] = useState();

function geolocation () {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        setLat(lat)
        setLong(long)
        console.log(latitude)
        console.log(longitude)
      });
    }


function getData () {
const url = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=56e420e8280d4f05a3593154212107&q=${lat},${long}&aqi=no`;
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        (response.data);
        console.log(response);
        
        
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
        return error
      });
    

}

 geolocation()
getData()
```

but lat and long are undefined in the url.

Am i close to the solution or do I need to change all the logic ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getData` inside a `React.useEffect`, which will be fired every time `lat` or `long` is changed.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!lat || !long) return;
  getData();
}, [lat, long]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use UseEffect like Martin Brandhaug told me, I am able to get the data.

But I can't use it after the return even if I put it into a state :

```
const Home = () => {

  const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
  const [long, setLong] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

function geolocation () {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        setLat(latitude);
        setLong(longitude);
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(long);
        
      });
    }

function getData () {
const url = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=56e420e8280d4f05a3593154212107&q=${lat},${long}&aqi=no`;
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(data);
        
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
        return error
      });
    

}

geolocation()

useEffect(() => {
  if (!lat || !long) return;
  getData();
}, [lat, long]);

console.log(data);

    return (

    <React.Fragment>
   
      <div className= "Actual_weather_container">
        
          <Search />
          <Geolocalisation />
          <Weather />
      </div>
      <div className= "Future_weather_container">
      </div>
  </React.Fragment> 
  )  

    }
```